# Fourier transformation (fft) for Time Series, but both ends of cleaned data move towards each other

Tags: python, time, coordinates, fft, series

I have a time serie that represents the X and the Z coordinate in a virtual environment.

```
X = np.array(df["X"])
Z = np.array(df["Z"])
```

Both the X and the Z coordinates contain noise from a different source. To filter out the noise I'd like to use a Fourier Transform.
After some research I used the code from https://medium.com/swlh/5-tips-for-working-with-time-series-in-python-d889109e676d to denoise my data.

```
def fft_denoiser(x, n_components, to_real=True):
    n = len(x)

    # compute the fft
    fft = np.fft.fft(x, n)

    # compute power spectrum density
    # squared magnitud of each fft coefficient
    PSD = fft * np.conj(fft) / n

    # keep high frequencies
    _mask = PSD > n_components
    fft = _mask * fft

    # inverse fourier transform
    clean_data = np.fft.ifft(fft)

    if to_real:
        clean_data = clean_data.real

    return clean_data
```

After setting the n_components I like to use the cleaned data. Which goes pretty well, as I plotted for the X-coordinate:

[image]

Only at the beginning and the end, the cleaned data suddenly move towards each others values... Can somebody help or expain to me what causes this, and how I can overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're having this issue is because the FFT implicitly assumes that the provided input signal is periodic. If you repeat your raw data, you see that at each period there is a large discontinuity (as the signal goes from ~20 back down to ~5). Once some higher frequency components are removed you see the slightly less sharp discontinuity at the edges (a few samples at the start and a few samples at the end).

To avoid this situation, you can do the filtering in the time-domain using a linear FIR filter, which can process the data sequence without the periodicity assumption.

For the purpose of this answer I constructed a synthetic test signal (which you can use to recreate the same conditions), but you can obviously use your own data instead:

```
# Generate synthetic signal for testing purposes
fs = 1 # Hz
f0 = 0.002/fs
f1 = 0.01/fs
dt = 1/fs
t = np.arange(200, 901)*dt
m = (25-5)/(t[-1]-t[0])
phi = 4.2
x = 5 + m*(t-t[0]) + 2*np.sin(2*np.pi*f0*t) + 1*np.sin(2*np.pi*f1*t+phi) + 0.2*np.random.randn(len(t))
```

Now to design the filter we can take the inverse transform of the `_mask` (instead of applying the mask):

```
import numpy as np

# Design denoising filter
def freq_sampling_filter(x, threshold):
  n = len(x)

  # compute the fft
  fft = np.fft.fft(x, n)

  # compute power spectrum density
  # squared magnitud of each fft coefficient
  PSD = fft * np.conj(fft) / n

  # keep frequencies with large contributions
  _mask = PSD > threshold
  _coff = np.fft.fftshift(np.real(np.fft.ifft(_mask)))
  return _coff

coff = freq_sampling_filter(x, threshold)
```

The `threshold` is a tunable parameter which would be chosen to keep enough of the frequency components you'd like to keep and get rid of the unwanted frequency components. That is of course highly subjective.

Then we can simply apply the filter with [`scipy.signal.filtfilt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html):

```
from scipy.signal import filtfilt

# apply the denoising filter
cleaned = filtfilt(coff, 1, x, padlen=len(x)-1, padtype='constant')
```

For the purpose of illustration, using a `threshold` of 10 with the above generated synthetic signal yields the following raw data (variable `x`) and cleaned data (variable `cleaned`):
[image]

The choice of `padtype` to `'constant'` ensures that the filtered values start and end at the start and end values of the unfiltered data.

***Alternative***

As was posted in comments, `filtfilt` may be expensive for longer data sets.
As an alternative, the filtering can be performed using FFT-based convolution by using [`scipy.fftconvolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html). Note that in this case, there is no equivalent of the `padtype` argument of `filtfilt`, so we need to manually pad the signal to avoid edge effects at the start and end.

```
n = len(x)
# Manually pad signal to avoid edge effects
x_padded = np.concatenate((x[0]*np.ones(n-1), x, x[-1]*np.ones((n-1)//2)))
# Filter using FFT-based convolution
cleaned = fftconvolve(x_padded, coff, mode='same')
# Extract result (remove data from padding)
cleaned = cleaned[2*(n-1)//2:-n//2+1]
```

For reference, here are some benchmark comparisons (timings in seconds, so smaller is better) for the above signal of length 700:

```
filtfilt    : 0.3831593
fftconvolve : 0.00028040000000029153
```

Note that relative performance would vary, but FFT-based convolution is expected to perform comparatively better as the signal gets longer.

Comment: Such a clear answer! Thank you so much, this was exactly what I was looking for! One problem when applying this to my own data, is that my data is very large (around 20.000 instances). Applying the filter with spicy.signal.filtfilt takes a lot of time... Unfortunately I have to do this for a lot of datasets.. Would you happen to know a way to speed up the process? Many thanks!

Comment: I used `filtfilt` in this answer because you didn't mention large datasets, and it made the solution simpler. But I believe that for odd `n` you could add `n-1` times the first value at the start and another `(n-1)/2` times the last value at the end, then use `fftconvolve` and get rid of the first `3*(n-1)/2` outputs. Might make it into an official answer/update when I get a chance.

Comment: @SleuthEye what is the `threshold` in the `freq_sampling_filter` function? or did you want to write `n_components` instead? for reproducibility, what is the value you used for the argument of the function in the test raw data that you created?

Comment: @msh855 I've updated the answer to include the value of `threshold` I've used in the example for reproducibility. That said, I've use the variable `threshold` because I believe it correspond better to the idea that FFT values above that threshold are kept, rather than the `n_components` of the OP's `fft_denoiser` function parameter which suggests that a specified integer number of frequency components are kept.